# Unable to remove dialog background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, customdialog

Hello there I'm trying to remove the background of my dialog with

`getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

and it worked fine

But after implementing the shadow effect for my dialog this issue comes up again even if the background drawable is set to transparent

this is the line I have added

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
```

This is a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zeqPtpL6uFlg4pizpf8T-WMi3fbZwbIZ/view?usp=sharing) of it

Full code

**sort_image_dialog_fragment.java**

```
 public class sort_image_dialoge_fragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_image, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dialog_rounded_background);

        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0.8f);
            getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme;
    }
}
```

**sort_image.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="Sort by"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lite_grey"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/divider_line_sort_by"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/sort_textView"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/lite_grey"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/latest_sort_textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="Latest"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/lite_grey"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/most_popular_sort_textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/latest_sort_textView"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="Most Popular"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/lite_grey"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/latest_sort_radio_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/most_popular_sort_radio_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:checked="true" />

                </RadioGroup>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

The issue not related to the layout because whatever layout you assign to a dialog; the dialog applies it to its squared window; and the dialog window is white rectangle by default (i.e. doesn't have rounded corners).
The outside part of this rectangle layout is dimmed by default.

Therefore the white color you see on the corners is related to the dialog window background.

#### Solution

So, in order to make a rounded corners dialog; you have to change that on its window with below 2 steps:

- **Step 1:** Create a theme in the themes.xml/styles.xml that removes the dialog window background:

```
    <style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Apply this theme by overriding getTheme() in your custom `DialogFragment` class:

```
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme;
}
```

- **Step 2:**: Create a rounded drawable exactly with your card radius (20dp):

res\drawable\rounded_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Apply this to the dialogFragment view using `view.setBackgroundResource()` and remove other window calls that you provided in `onCreateView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_image, container, false);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background);
    return view;
}
```

UPDATE:

- Make sure to use the lower case `@null` not `@Null`.
- The `sort_image_dialog_fragment.java` should now look like:

```
public class sort_image_dialog_fragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_image, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme;
    }


}
```

#### Result:

[image]

**Side note:** the name convention of classes should start with upper case, and follow camel case pattern; so the `sort_image_dialog_fragment` would be `SortImageDialgFragment` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,ok I understand all the steps just have a doubt about the first step can you tell me what exactly I have to do I don't understand the first step very well

Comment: ok I have tried your solution but there is a problem the entire layout is showing instead of just the card view, ok I want to clear a thing I'm confused about in the first step of yours so probably I have messed up in the first step that's why this is showing up

Comment: Please change the match_parent to wrap_content in the RelativeLayout...

Comment: For the first step.. You need to change the default style of the dialog in order to remove the background by setting it to null. So you open the styles.xml or the themes.xml file add the new style in the answer... Then override the getTheme method in your sort_image_dialog_fragment.java class to include the new style

Comment: i used the wrap_content but it still having the same issue it showing the entier layout  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OdA6YjehL8MZY7c8aLddXYHTeCX0Vkvw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share sort_image_dialog_fragment.java class

Comment: i have add the style like this <style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme">@Null</style>

Comment: ok i have  update the sort_image_dialog_fragment.java

Comment: sorry but the issue is still there, I'm not getting entier layout but still, there is white background near the corners, and now there is another issue radio button is shifted slightly upwards and also the color changed to green which is white default

Comment: i think the issue of the radio buttons is related to the style

Comment: @VasantRaval The problem that you didn't remvoe the flags & attributes set to the window in the `sort_image_dialog_fragment.java ` ... Please check the UPDATE section in the answer.

Comment: For the layout issue ..try to return it to match_parent again

Comment: the layout is already match parent but the radio button issue is still there

Comment: as you said in the update section if I remove the IF statement which contains all the get dialog there is a black background now

Comment: how can i edit dialog_holo_light_frame so i can give corner radius directly or i create an XML which have capability of dialog_holo_light_frame of giving the shadow effect

Comment: @VasantRaval Looks like you've a different theme than mine that affects this black background; this didn't appear with me and also this shouldn't appear as the default behavior of the dialog is to have a dimmed background not black.. Can you limit this issue to a small project on Github so that I can deeply see it

Comment: return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme; solved it for me. Thanks!